# Updating map after zoom change

Tags: carto, geocoding, zoom

I'm building a map that uses a conditional statement to determine what data to load based on the zoom level. However, the conditional statement is only fired when the map first loads, as opposed to every time the zoom level changes. Is there a way to change the code to run on zoom load (i.e. to update every time the user zooms in or out) rather than the initial page load?

Comment: What library are you using to create map?

Comment: I'm using JavaScript

Comment: I meant name of the library. There are different libraries for creating an interactive map.

Comment: My apologies, I'm relatively new to programming. I'm using Carto VL to build my map

Answer (score 1):

All map libraries have events which help you to find out when map zoomed, clicked and panned. For example, if you're using `Leaflet.js`, map object has following listener for zoom:

```js
var initCenter = [42.444508, -76.499491];
var initZoom = 4;

var map = L.map('map').setView(initCenter, initZoom);

map.on('zoomend', function() {
    currentZoomLevel = map.getZoom();
    // Do your job
});
```

On the other hand, you can find map events for `CARTO` [here](https://carto.com/developers/carto-vl/v0.10.0/guides/interactivity-events/).

```js
map.on('move', {
    currentZoomLevel = map.getZoom();
    // Do your job
});
```